# How should I reshape my data to feed into pytorch GRU network?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, gru

I've been having problems getting my data to fit the dimensions required by pytorch GRU.

- My input is a 256-long float vector, in bathes of 64, so the size of a batch tensor is [64, 256]
- According to [pytorch documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generate/torch.nn.GRU.html), GRU takes input of size [batch_size, sequence_length, input_size]. Now i'm not sure if the sequence_length corresponds to the length of the output sequence, nor am I sure what the input_size would be here (256?).
- My GRU is supposed to take the whole vector as an input, generate output, and pass the output to the next gru cell as input. This is ought to continue until a sequence of 128 outputs is generated.
  [My idea for the GRU network (see the picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1zaA.png)
- Each of the outputs will be passed through 256 -> 42 fc layer and a token from the alphabet of 42 will be chosen.

What this network is going to do is take a 256-long encoded vector representation of a molecule and learn to generate the corresponding SELFIES string (text-based molecule representation), padded to the length of 128, with tokens from an alphabet of 42 'letters'.

Now, i have no idea how to reshape the input tensor for the GRU to accept it as an input, according to the drawing I attached.

Thanks in advance for your help.

I tried to torch.unsqueeze(1) the input tensor. This resulted in me getting an output of shape [64, 1, 256] which would be a batch of 64 one-token outputs in my model.

```py
class DecoderNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, num_layers, output_size, output_len):
        super(DecoderNet, self).__init__()
        
        # GRU parameters
        self.input_size = input_size # = 256
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size # = 256
        self.num_layers = num_layers # = 1
        
        # output token count
        self.output_size = output_size # = 42
        
        # output length or GRU time steps count
        self.output_len = output_len # = 128
        
        # pytorch.nn
        self.gru = nn.GRU(input_size=input_size, hidden_size=hidden_size, num_layers=num_layers)
        self.fc = nn.Linear(hidden_size, output_size)
        self.softmax = nn.Softmax(dim=2)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()

    def forward(self, x, h):
        out, h = self.gru(x, h)
        return out, h
    
    def init_hidden(self, batch_size):
        h0 = torch.zeros(self.num_layers, batch_size, self.hidden_size)
        return h0
```

Comment: what is your [batch_size, sequence_length, input_size]?

Comment: @Artist12 just edited my post - my batch size is obviously 64, but I am not sure about how to understand sequence_length or input_size in my case.

Comment: RNN models only accept sequential inputs, so as long as you figure out what's the 'seq_length' in your case, your problem should be solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, `nn.GRU` expects `(seq_len, batch_size, input_size)` as input. You need to create the layer with `batch_first=True` to give it `(batch_size, seq_len, input_size)`.

If your `x` has a shape of `(batch_size, seq_len)`, then you first need to add the inputs size dimensions with

```
x = x.unsqueeze(2)
```

to get a shape of `(batch_size, seq_len, input_size=1)`.

Alternatively, you can keep `batch_first=False` (the default) and swap the batch size and sequence length dimension, before or after the `unsqueeze()` like that:

```
x = x.transpose(1, 0)
```

**Important:** Do not use `reshape()` or `view()` to "fix" the shape of `x` (as indicated by the title question of your post), as this will [mess up your tensor](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/for-beginners-do-not-use-view-or-reshape-to-swap-dimensions-of-tensors/75524)!